# BlobstoreUploadHandler not being called when using Modules

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

Our mobile API is now being routed through to its own [Module](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/). When a client attempts to upload a file the URL returned from [create_upload_url()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions#create_upload_url) returns a 404.

The routes I've set in my **dispatch.yaml** should route the call correctly.

Does anyone know if the callback actually routes through **dispatch.yaml** or if it ignores it entirely?

**I just switched some of the Modules and can confirm that the BlobstoreUploadHandler is called via the default module. However, no error is presented e.g. 404 Handler not found**

I'm going to log an issue.